# Tsql Sorting an ORDER BY with WHERE

Tags: sql, .net, t-sql, microsoft-chart-controls

I am working on a .net chart control project and am new to sql. I want to be able to sort the date which is from a textbox input.

```
SELECT Employee.[First Name] + ' ' + Employee.[Last Name] AS 'Name',
sum(Time.[Total Hours]) AS 'Total Hours'
, FORMAT([Time].[Time in], 'd', 'en-gb') AS 'Worked On'
FROM Employee
inner join [Time] on
Employee.ID =  Time.EmployeeIdFK 
GROUP BY FORMAT([Time].[Time in], 'd', 'en-gb')
,Employee.[First Name] + ' ' + Employee.[Last Name]

--WHERE Time.[Time in] between '6/23/2016' and '7/26/2016'
```

So far after running the query I get. This is just a dummy.mdf i am testing out.

```
Name                                 Total Hours            Worked On
------------------------------------ ---------------------- -----------
Cola Coco                            11.3332033110278       23/07/2016
Cola Coco                            0.00417034752421024    26/07/2016
Lmimited Pepsi                       14.2175327702778       23/07/2016
Lmimited Pepsi                       2.9601598583878E-07    24/07/2016
Lmimited Pepsi                       1.05082415577342E-06   26/07/2016
```

I want to add

```
WHERE Time.[Time in] between '6/23/2016' and '7/26/2016'
```

or something similar so that I can just input the date from the text box.

Comment: What is the problem? You can add your WHERE clause right before the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Put Where BEFORE the group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--UPDATE--

Thank you for the comments, I have been placing the WHERE after GROUP BY which has been giving me an error.

```
 SELECT Employee.[First Name] + ' ' + Employee.[Last Name] AS 'Name',
 sum(Time.[Total Hours]) AS 'Total Hours'
 , FORMAT(Time.[Time in], 'd', 'en-gb') AS 'Worked On'
 FROM Employee
 inner join Time on
 Employee.ID = Time.EmployeeIdFK 
 WHERE Time.[Time in] between '6/23/2016' and '7/26/2016'
 GROUP BY FORMAT(Time.[Time in], 'd', 'en-gb')
 ,Employee.[First Name] + ' ' + Employee.[Last Name]

Name                                 Total Hours            Worked On
------------------------------------ ---------------------- -----------
Cola Coco                            11.3332033110278       23/07/2016
Lmimited Pepsi                       14.2175327702778       23/07/2016
Lmimited Pepsi                       2.9601598583878E-07    24/07/2016
```

This works fine now.